# Merging df in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Say I have two DataFrames

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2], 'B':[3,4]}, index = [0,1])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B':[8,9], 'C':[10,11]}, index = [1,2])
```

I want to merge so that any values in `df1` are overwritten in there is a value in `df2` at that location and any new values in `df2` are added including the new rows and columns.

The result should be:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  3  nan
1  2  8  10
2 nan 9  11
```

I've tried `combine_first` but that causes only nan values to be overwritten
updated has the issue where new rows are created rather than overwritten
merge has many issues.

I've tried writing my own function

```
def take_right(df1, df2, j, i):
    print (df1)
    print (df2)
    try:
        s1 = df1[j][i]
    except:
        s1 = np.NaN
    try:
        s2 = df2[j][i]
    except:
        s2 = np.NaN
    
    if math.isnan(s2):
        #print(s1)
        return s1
    else:
       # print(s2)
        return s2
    
def combine_df(df1, df2):
    
    rows = (set(df1.index.values.tolist()) | set(df2.index.values.tolist()))
    #print(rows)
    columns = (set(df1.columns.values.tolist()) | set(df2.columns.values.tolist()))
    #print(columns)
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    #df.columns = columns
    for i in rows:
        #df[:][i]=[]
        for j in columns:
                
                df = df.insert(int(i), j, take_right(df1,df2,j,i), allow_duplicates=False)
   # print(df)
                
    return df
```

This won't add new columns or rows to an empty DataFrame.

Thank you!!

Comment: Are you sure `combine_first` doesn't work, and you weren't just doing it in the wrong order?

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to create an empty output dataframe with the union of columns and indices from df1 and df2 and then use the `df.update` method to assign their values into the out_df

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2], 'B':[3,4]}, index = [0,1])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B':[8,9], 'C':[10,11]}, index = [1,2])


out_df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns = df1.columns.union(df2.columns),
    index = df1.index.union(df2.index),
)
out_df.update(df1)
out_df.update(df2)
out_df
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why does `combine_first` not work?

```
df = df2.combine_first(df1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     A  B     C
0  1.0  3   NaN
1  2.0  8  10.0
2  NaN  9  11.0
```